# Using conditions with CSV rows

Tags: python

I'm looking at creating a very basic username and password program using an external CSV file. The program allows the user to input a username and password, afterwards an if statement checks whether the username and password match that of a row in the CSV document. If so then the corresponding user information is displayed.

The issue I'm having is to with my `else:` statement. If the user details don't match that of a row (wrong username or password) a notification should display. By adding an else line though, it checks per line so I receive more than one "Details entered incorrectly." messages. Also if the credentials are correct, the user information is displayed alongside "Details entered incorrectly" for every other row.

```
import csv

Username = input("Username: ")
Password = input("Password: ")

with open('data.csv', 'rt', newline='') as file:

    open_file = csv.reader(file)

for row in open_file:
    if row[0] == Username and row[1] == Password:
        print("Secret phrase: ", row[2])
    else:
        print("Incorrect user details.")
```

Any ideas on how I could alter my code to fix this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something lovely in python, called the for-else. This else clause, belonging to a for-loop instead of an if, is executed if the loops exits normally (the iterator runs out):

```
for row in open_file:
    if row[0] == Username and row[1] == Password:
        print("Secret phrase: ", row[2])
        break # stop searching and skip the for-else.
else:
    print("Incorrect user details.")
```

---

I don't quite understand what you mean with

> Also if the credentials are correct, the user information is displayed alongside "Details entered incorrectly" for every other row.
>   Could you elaborate or give an example?

Comment: This doesn't stop the "Incorrect user details." message appearing if the user details match that of the second row for example - the message appears with the user information below.

Comment: @user3149629: I don't get what you mean, could you perhaps give an example csv and credentials for which it fails?